# document.write, onload and variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, onload

I've been struggling all day with the document.write and the onLoad function.

If you consider a JS code like this one =>

```
window.i = 0;
console.log(i + " //should be 0");

document.write("<scr"+"ipt onLoad='onA1Ready()' src='a1.js'><\/sc"+"ript>");

function onA1Ready(){
    document.write("<scr"+"ipt onLoad='onA2Ready()' src='a2.js'><\/sc"+"ript>");
}

function onA2Ready(){
    console.log(i + " //should be 2");
}
```

and a1.js beeing like this =>

```
i++;
console.log(i + " //should be 1");
```

and a2.js beeing quite similar =>

```
i++;
console.log(i + " //should be 2");
```

I'd expect the last console output to be equal to 2, but instead here is what I get out of the console =>

```
0 //should be 0     test.js (line 2)
1 //should be 1     a1.js (line 2)
i is not defined    ERROR i++; a2.js (line 1)
onA2Ready is not defined
```

I guess this issue is scope related, but I can't figure how.

It would be great if any of you had an idea of what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on Chrome 16 and everything ran as expected. However, in the latest FF I got the error you described.

My advice is to stop using *the evil* `document.write()` to dynamically load scripts. Instead use DOM methods. I have written a little function `myLoader()` that can help you

```
window.i = 0;
console.log(i + " //should be 0");

var myLoader = function(filename, fun) {
  var head   = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type= 'text/javascript';
  script.src = filename;
  if(typeof fun === 'function'){ script.onload = fun; }
  head.appendChild(script);
};


myLoader('a1.js', function(){
  myLoader('a2.js', function() {
    console.log(i + " //should be 2");
  });
});
```

Try it out.

The output I get

```
0 //should be 0         a0.js (line 2)
1 //should be 1         a1.js (line 2)
2 //should be 2         a2.js (line 2)
2 //should be 2         a0.js (line 17)
```

Comment: Seems great, I'll give it a try.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't working on IE 9 in quirks mode.  The onload function isn't called.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would Strongly suggest not using `document.write`. It's messy and unnecessary.

Adding a script tag is much better handled as such:

```
var addScriptWithOnLoad = function(src, fn) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', src);
    s.onload = fn;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
};
```

Next you really shouldn't be using the global scope like that, you are relying on the browser playing nice, which is never a safe bet. You should rather be passing data between functions. That is however a bit outside the scope of this answer.

the following script tag, placed in the head of a [web page](http://www.zell.io/t.html), produces your intended result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.i = 0;
    var addJS = function(src, fn) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', src);
        s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        s.onload = fn;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    };

    console.log(i + " //should be 0");

    var fn1 = function() {
        console.log();
        addJS('a2.js', fn2);
    };

    var fn2 = function() {
        console.log(i + " //should be 2");
    };

    addJS('a1.js', fn1);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the following

`window.i = 0;

document.write("<scr"+"ipt onload='onA1Ready()' src='a1.js'><\/sc"+"ript>");

function onA1Ready(){
 document.write("<scr"+"ipt onload='onA2Ready()' src='a2.js'><\/sc"+"ript>");
}

function onA2Ready(){
 console.log(window.i + " //onA2Ready");
}`

with a1.js =>

`window.i++;
console.log(window.i + "//a1.js");`

and a2.js =>

`window.i++;
console.log(window.i + "//a2.js");`

console logs this =>

`NaN//a2.js
a2.js (line 2)
onA2Ready is not defined`

Comment: Regarding to the global scope, I won't do that on the actual project, this snippet was only intended to demonstrate my problem here. Anyway, your solution is nice, quite the same as jm- I guess. Thanks again, Erwin

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that onA1Ready() is called onLoad which writes another function to be called onLoad which never is called as the document is already loaded.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for helping, I'm quite a newbie with javascript :(

The console output says : onA2Ready is not defined, doesn't it mean, the function is beeing called but is somehow not visible within that particular scope?